# How to properly attach copper pipe to steel framing?

Tags: plumbing, copper-tubing

What is a code-approved way to secure copper pipe to metal framing members which minimizes heat transfer and potential reactivity between the two different metals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use plastic bushings. I couldn't find a photo with pipe, but here's one with electrical:

[image]

This gives you the benefit of separation of materials and also a 'slip joint' to handle the expansion/contraction of pipes so they're not making lots of noises rubbing against framing members.

To attach the pipe *to* the stud, you can use pipe clamps like this:

[image]

Comment: I think the OP wants to secure the pipe to the metal stud, not just pass through it. Some rigidity may be needed.

Comment: @bib oh, good call! I'll update the answer.